# How to stop a force getting applied to SKSprtieNode?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, sknode

I have couple of small paddles alligned next to each other with size of roughly 50x10 moving from left to right and right to left constantly, which would also randomly stop moving from time to time and become stationary. There is a ball that falls off towards them, and upon hitting a paddle, if its not moving and is stationary, the ball will bounce off it and go straight back up. However, if the paddles are moving and the ball hits one of the paddles during that time, instead of the ball hitting them and going right back up, it hits the paddle and starts moving either right or left (depending on which direction the paddles are moving) while going back up. I'm trying to have the ball go right back up even if it hits the paddle while its moving (pretty much a forever bouncing ball against the paddles).

I have tried couple of different ways to solve this, but I think I'm missing something important that's making it behave like this. Here is the code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
        let greenPaddle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Green")
        var ball = SKSpriteNode()

        let ballCategory: UInt32 = 1 << 0
        let greenPaddleCategory: UInt32 = 1 << 1

        override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

            self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

            greenPaddle.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: frame.size.height / -6.5)
            greenPaddle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: greenPaddle.size)
            greenPaddle.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
            greenPaddle.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

            greenPaddle.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = greenPaddleCategory
            greenPaddle.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory


          ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Red")
          ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2)
          ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 2)
          ball.physicsBody!.friction = 0
          ball.physicsBody!.restitution = 1
          ball.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
          ball.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

         ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ballCategory
         ball.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = greenPaddleCategory

         addChild(circle)
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        let bodyA = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyA : contact.bodyB
        let bodyB = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyB : contact.bodyA

        if (bodyA.categoryBitMask) == ballCategory && (bodyB.categoryBitMask) == greenPaddleCategory {

            greenPaddle.physicsBody!.friction = 0
            greenPaddle.physicsBody!.restitution = 0  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand the problem; however, you have forgotten to set the physics world in the didmovetoview.

```
 self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

If the problem is that the contact do not work, this would work:)

Comment: I have that it in, forgot to mention it here. i'm trying to have the ball bounce off the paddles in a straight line (down and up). For instance, if the paddle is moving from left to right, and the ball hits the paddle while its moving, the ball will go up while moving towards to the right and not straight back up, if that makes sense